# xcode UITextfield inside view is not editable

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, uistackview

I have added few textfield inside a stackview and under the stackview i have added 2views so I could create to new columns.  Inside that views i placed my textfileds. Now when I run it,  Tje textfileds are not editable.  I tried addint a new textfield  outside the stackview and its working just well.

Can you help me with this?  I added the textfield by dragging them into my contoller so no codes are involved.

```
<stackView contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillEqually" alignment="top" spacing="20" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="7mt-mS-PCA" userLabel="Add Project">
    <rect key="frame" x="40" y="110" width="1286" height="289"/>
    <subviews>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" semanticContentAttribute="playback" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VRJ-lA-xQb">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="633" height="289"/>
            <subviews>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Orderer" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Upf-s1-e9P">
                    <rect key="frame" x="10" y="10" width="47" height="16"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="13"/>
                    <color key="textColor" white="0.33333333329999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="jg6-wU-2yV">
                    <rect key="frame" x="10" y="36" width="613" height="30"/>
                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                    <connections>
                        <action selector="OrdererInput:" destination="VWK-Bs-FSH" eventType="editingDidEnd" id="GhB-dm-tKQ"/>
                    </connections>
                </textField>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Constuction Area" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Naf-MF-mdY">
                    <rect key="frame" x="10" y="76" width="105" height="16"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="13"/>
                    <color key="textColor" white="0.33333333329999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
                <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="j44-Dv-X7S">
                    <rect key="frame" x="10" y="102" width="613" height="30"/>
                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                    <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                </textField>
```

Here's part of the code.

Comment: please show some code/ storyboard screenshot and even better could be a video of this

Comment: @Olympiloutre , I already edited my question, added part of the code